# ¿Como agregar instagram feed en posts Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Llevo varios días intentando solucionar el siguiente problema:

Estoy desarrollando un directorio comercial mediante Wordpress, cada comercio es un post que contiene varios campos como lo es su nombre, opciones de contácto, etc. Entre ellos, hay un campo que solicita la URL de instagram. Ahora bien, **¿Como puedo mostrar el feed (Obteniendo la URL desde el campo en el backend) en el frontend?**

Como es de esperar, habrá mas de un comercio. Por lo tanto, en cada post el valor del campo es diferente, lo que debe hacer que muestre el feed correspondiente a cada comercio.

Estoy trabajando con Elementor y una plantilla creada con el theme builder que provee. No habría problema en instalar plugins extras. Tampoco habría problema en modificar código. ¿Como solucionarías?

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

**EDIT 1**
He intentado con toda clases de plugins, porque código entiendo pero acá se me hizo dificil. Básicamente, he encontrado plugins que me permiten especificar el usuario del feed via elementor, pero no me permite rescatarlo de mis campos personalizados (Para incluirlo en la plantilla). Entonces, solo podría poner un usuario para todos los comercios, y no es la idea.

Comment: Puedes agregar lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la API OEmbed de instagram https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed

Esta te permite incrustar un feed de instagram usando una URL de este tipo:

```
$oembed_url="https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/instagram_oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/{$USERNAME}/&access_token={$ACCESS_TOKEN}";
```

Puedes obtener el contenido usando

```
$result=json_decode( file_get_contents($oembed_url) , true);
```

Obteniendo una estructura como esta:

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"author_name": "USERNAME",
"provider_name": "Instagram",
"provider_url": "https://www.instagram.com/",
"type": "rich",
"width": 658,
"html": "<blockquote class=\"instagram-media\" data-instgrm-ca...",
"thumbnail_width": 640,
"thumbnail_height": 640
}
```

Donde `$result['html']` contendra el HTML del feed. Al incrustar este codigo en tu pagina, invocara la libreria embed.js para realizar obtener el resto de los elementos visuales.

Comment: Voy a intentarlo. Sin embargo, tengo otra duda: ¿Como puedo recuperar el valor de los campos personalizados mediante código?